# Create a popup view in Xcode 4

Tags: iphone, ios, uipopovercontroller

I have a tap recognition in one of my views, on tap of which I should display a popup view from existing nib files. I have added the following code

```
FeedTabReplyView *d = [[FeedTabReplyView alloc]initWithNibName:@"FeedTabReplyView" bundle:nil];
//d.delegate = self;
//create popover and put V2 in the popover view
UIPopoverController *popoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:d]; 
//popoverController.delegate = self;  //optional
CGSize size = CGSizeMake(325, 75);
popoverController.popoverContentSize = size;
[popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:recognizer.view.frame inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
```

but it throws an exception:

> 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIPopoverController
>   initWithContentViewController:] called when not running under
>   UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad.'

Answer (score 2):

`UIPopoverController` works only for the iPad, however for the iPhone there is a very good class [WEPopover](https://github.com/werner77/WEPopover)

its very easy to use, and it has almost all the `UIPopoverController` methods and properties

Answer (score 1):

**Omar** is right.

From Apple doc:

> Popover controllers are for use exclusively on iPad devices. Attempting to create one on other devices results in an exception.

Instead of using a third part API, why don't you use `UIActionSheet`?

If you need to develop an universal app, based on the interface idiom, you could just create a popover (iPad) or an action sheet (iPhone).